Is there a way to supply a secret to AWS Batch as a parameter?
I'm submitting a job to AWS Batch using the Console, and need to supply a secret token as a command-line parameter. How can I do so?
"command": [
  "script.sh",
  "--param1"
  "Ref::name1",
  "--token",
  "<secret_token_string>
]

Explored Solutions:

Listing it as a parameter in the AWS Batch job submission GUI.


This is unacceptable because it would be provided in plaintext.


Using AWS "Secrets Manager"


I'm not aware of how to do so; I can only get it to work with env vars. Setting an environment variable and supplying "${var_name}" directly in the command list didn't work either.


Using "Systems Manager Parameter Store" with a "SecretString".


I also couldn't get this to work either. I don't know if it's designed to operate with AWS Batch, since providing the ARN and using "{{ssm:param_name}}" both didn't work.


You do not want a secret to be injected into command that go into logs. This is why Batch does not allow interpolation of environment variables within the container command parameter. Interpolating environment variables should be done within your application code.
